# Linux "free -m": Total, used and free memory values don't add up

Tags: linux, memory, free-command

On a linux system, while using "free", following are the values:

```
         total      used      free    shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:  26755612    873224    389320    286944    25493068    25311948
Swap:        0         0         0
```

The total, used and free values don't add up. I'm expecting total = used + free.

**Question:**
What am I missing here?

Comment: @buttifulbuttefly My understanding so far was that buff/cache is a subset of total.

Comment: Agreeing with Andreas. My understand was the same. @buttifulbutterfly, plz add if something's missing. I have a tomcat server running on this machine. Will it pick up memory from buff/cache if needed? thx.

Comment: @MichaelMassey What Linux distribution/version/hardware is that?

Comment: @shekharsuman Mine does not ;-) (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) - thats why I asked for the distribution. Which Linux system are you using?

Comment: @Andreas- Linux **`CENTOS-7`** 3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64

Comment: @Andreas Linux 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 x86_64 (RHEL 7.1)

Comment: Bottom line: the output of free has changed recently: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=190614. See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180278/how-to-disable-procps-ng-3-3-10-free-wide-output-format

Comment: Thx @Andreas. It clarifies all doubts.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For the main memory, the actual size of memory can be calculated as **`used+free+buffers+cache`** OR **`used+free+buffers/cache`** because **`buffers/cache = buffer+cache`**.

The man page of `free` highlights **`used`** as `Used memory (calculated as total - free - buffers - cache)`

As the man page of free says :-

> ***total***  Total installed memory (MemTotal and SwapTotal in /proc/meminfo)
>
> ***used***   Used memory (calculated as total - free - buffers - cache)
>
> ***free***   Unused memory (MemFree and SwapFree in /proc/meminfo)
>
> ***shared*** Memory used (mostly) by tmpfs (Shmem in /proc/meminfo, 
>                 on kernels 2.6.32, displayed as zero if not available)
>
> ***buffers***   Memory used by kernel buffers (Buffers in /proc/meminfo)
>
> ***cache***  Memory  used  by  the  page  cache and slabs (Cached and Slab in
>                 /proc/meminfo)
>
> ***buff / cache***  Sum of buffers and cache
>
> ***available***  Estimation of how much memory  is  available  for  starting  new applications,  without swapping. Unlike the data provided by the               cache or free fields, this field takes into account  page  cache and also that not all reclaimable memory slabs will be reclaimed due to items being in use (MemAvailable in /proc/meminfo, available on kernels 3.14, emulated on kernels 2.6.27+, otherwise the same as free)

In your case,

---

> 873224(used) + 389320(free) + 25493068(buff/cache) = 26755612(total)

---

Comment: It looks like Available = Free - Used + Shared + Buff/Cache, so I don't understand the logic behind it. Why the Available is not simply the Total minus the Used

Comment: @NadavB - For this, you need to deeply study about tmpfs filesystem, buffers and cache. It is not that simple to answer your question in a few words!

Comment: Available is not simply free - used + shared + buff/cache.  It includes only part of "cache", as not all cache can be reclaimed for various reasons.  It's also only an estimate because it tries to represent how much memory could be allocated without swapping, but that's not easy to predict due to the swap algorithm being so complex/fuzzy.

Answer (score 14):

Linux likes to cache every file that it opens.  Every time you open a file for reading, Linux will cache it but it will drop those caches if it needs the memory for something more important -- like when a process on the system wants to allocate more memory.  These caches in memory simply make Linux faster when the same files are used over and over again.  Instead of actually going to disk every time it wants to read the file, it just gets it from memory and memory is a lot faster that disk.  That is why your system shows 25493068 used in buff/cache but also shows 25311948 available.  Much of that cached data can be freed if the system needs it.

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeB. It clears my doubts.