# My server's total memory doesn't match with USED + FREE memory. I'm using linux free command

Tags: linux, memory, server, free-command

I'm not really sure what's happening with my memory. I have **31G** total of memory, used is **1G**, and free is **9G**.

My question is, why is it, I only have 9G and 1G = 10G. It's far from the total memory which is 31G.

I'm hoping to look around **1G used** and **~29G free.** Can anyone help explain about this?

```
$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          31757        1264        9377         342       21114       29855
Swap:          2047           2        2044

$ free -g
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:             31           1           9           0          20          29
Swap:             1           0           1
```

Comment: Those numbers add up. Why do you ignore the rest of the columns?

Comment: I didn't include it because I thought it shouldn't be include. Based from this example ( http://www.linuxnix.com/find-ram-size-in-linuxunix/ ) - as you can see the total memory usage = used + free memory. However, after checking the man and this post ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772369/linux-free-m-total-used-and-free-memory-values-dont-add-up ) I realized that it should be included. Anyway, thank you for your comment as it is a very helpful idea. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
buff/cache: 21114
```

Your operating system uses "free" memory for [caching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache).

From wikipedia:

> Usually, all physical memory not directly allocated to applications is
>   used by the operating system for the page cache. Since the memory
>   would otherwise be idle and is easily reclaimed when applications
>   request it, there is generally no associated performance penalty [...]